# Categorizing MySQL result array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a function that returns database results like so:

```
<?php print_r($homepagematches; ?> 
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [matchid] => 30
        [matchtitle] => Testing This!
        [matchaverage] => 1
        [matchyoutubecode] => New Match
        [casterid] => 1
        [matchtype] => 
        [matchdate] => 2013-05-24 02:19:49
        [matchcasteryoutube] => http://youtube.com/huskystarcraft
        [matchcaster] => HuskyStarcraft
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [matchid] => 27
        [matchtitle] => Psy vs Camara
        [matchaverage] => 1
        [matchyoutubecode] => nefC9vkMfG8
        [casterid] => 1
        [matchtype] => 
        [matchdate] => 2013-05-24 02:13:10
        [matchcasteryoutube] => http://youtube.com/huskystarcraft
        [matchcaster] => HuskyStarcraft
    )
```

The function returns all matches within the last 3 days, What I am trying to figure out is how to reform the array so that I can display the matches under the day in which they were posted. I know a foreach loop is probably required for this, I just can't get my head around the concept I would need to implement.

```
$matchdate = '';
 foreach($this->data['homepagematches'] as $match){
    if($matchdate != date('m/d', strtotime($match['matchdate'])) || $matchdate == ''){
    $homematch[date('m/d', strtotime($match['matchdate']))] = array(
    "matchtitle" => $match['matchtitle']);
    }
```

Basically I need the Array to look like:

```
Array 
(
[05/24] => Array
        (
              [matchid] =>30
              [matchtitle] => Testing This!
              [matchyoutubecode] => New Match
              [casterid] = 1
         )
 )
```

Comment: or you can query the `matchdate` field and extract only the right results. That way is less pressure on mysql (doesn't return too many results) and also you don't need to write php code to do what mysql should've done in the first place.

Comment: I am getting the correct results. The query only returns rows that will indeed be displayed. Are you saying instead of one query pulling all matches within the last 3 days, I need to have three different queries each pulling for a certain day, ie today, yesterday.. ? This seems like more load for the server to handle. Thanks for your quick response! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it.

```
foreach($this->data['homepagematches'] as $match){
    $tag = date('m/d', strtotime($match['matchdate']));
    $data[$tag][] = array(
        "matchid" => $match['matchid'],
        "matchtitle" => $match['matchtitle'],
        "matchyoutubecode" => $match['matchyoutubecode'],
        "casterid" => $match['casterid']
    );
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andy. Exactly what I needed. You're a boss!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$MatchesByDate = array();
foreach($homepagematches as $match) {
    list($matchdate,$time) = explode(" ",$match["matchdate"]); //split field into date and time
    if( !isset($MatchesByDate[$matchdate]) )
         $MatchesByDate[$matchdate] = array(); // If the array for that date doesnt exist yet make it
    $MatchesByDate[$matchdate][] = $match; //Use the matchdate as a key and add to the array
}
```